# Port manipulation: Coding for two chips

Tags: memory-usage, port-mapping, algorithm, programming-sequence

I am using Arduino Nano to test a code that will be ported on an ATTiny chip, which will need to perform operations at a frequency near clock maximum, calling for a *very* succinct coding.

**My goal: to streamline coding for two different chips in one file with the least repetitions and operations possible.**

Specifically, I have a pin

```
#ifdef TIMSK0 //Nano vs atTiny
const byte  wavePin  = 5,
            waveBit  = B100000;
      byte *wavePort = &PORTD;
#define NANO
#else
const byte  wavePin  = 0,
            waveBit  = PB1;
      byte *wavePort = &PORTB;
#endif
```

Notice the pointer? It works, but I have the impression this may not be the most efficient option, as it adds an operation (by looking up the reference). I have also planned to do constantly check which chip we are loading it in this fashion

```
#ifdef NANO
  PORTD
#else
  PORTB
#endif
  |=   waveBit *  waveOn);
#ifdef NANO
  PORTD
#else
  PORTB
#endif
  &= ~(waveBit * !waveOn));
```

But again, while this may be perfectly fine in operations, it hurts the eyes and is rather repetitive.

Is there a way to create a direct access to a port?

Comment: Are you familiar with C++ Macros?

Comment: Not yet? Tell me more :D

Comment: Do you mean to do something like `#define WAVEPORT PORTD`?

Comment: StarCat you opened me a can of worms and I love it :D Thanks it actually works!

Comment: Great! That is actually more or less what I meant.